# Natural sort order (human sort order) in R list.files()

Tags: r, natural-sort

Is there a simple way to sort files in natural order (otherwise known as human order), i.e. file9.csv comes before file10.csv?  list.files() seems to have no options for the sort order.

There are plenty of implementations in other languages (e.g. [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html)) , and [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Natural_sorting) only has solutions in C, Perl, Python, etc.

Comment: try gtools `mixedsort`

Comment: @baptiste, post as answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Human sort" is a mad man's illusion available only on hypothetical AI systems, but only when having proper context knowledge.

To this end you should rather use some quick regexp to extract meta-data from file names and use them to order files:

```
files<-c("file9.txt","file10.txt");
as.numeric(gsub('^file([0123456789]*)\\.txt$','\\1',files))->fileNum;
files[order(fileNum)]
```

Comment: That's a nice and generic way to solve the problem.  I didn't want to get to grips with regex for this, so I looped through the list of filenames and used strsplit(files[i], "...") to extract the number sequence.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mixedsort()` or `mixedorder()` from package `gtools`, as pointed out by [@baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste) in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could try naming it as file09.csv...

```
filenames <- paste0("file", 0:20, ".txt")
new_filenames <- sub("file([[:digit:]])\\.txt", "file0\\1\\.txt", filenames)
is_different <- new_filenames != filenames
file.rename(filenames[is_different], new_filenames[is_different])
```

Comment: That does answer the OP's question.

Comment: There are tools (such as Total Commander's multifile rename) that make this kind of renaming very easy across even hundreds of files.